# Best design practice for saving many coordinates in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, coordinates

I'm a new student to the world of designing databases and I've been requested to model one for an app that will have about 5-6 forms with the only thing in common being that they must allow the user to select and save coordinates(in long and lat) from a map. My doubt is where to locate those fields, I have come up with two options but not sure they are the best practice or if there's a better one.

Option 1: 
A table for each form that includes their id, necessary fields and longitude and latitude for each of them.

Option 2: 
Same as above but with a sepparate table for all coordinates, like with it's own id and fields as FK's for all the other form tables which will only have values if the coordinates to be recorded are related to them or not. Something like this:

[An example on how I see my option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbrYS.png)

I thought of option 2 because option 1 seemed repetitive with having to add lat and long fields on each table and now I can't decide!. Of course, I'm sure you would know better and I appreciate every advice I can get.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: I doubt we can answer for your specific case, but in general, the database needn't have a structure in any way resembling the form(s)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. So, would it be safe to believe you're telling me both options are ok?.

Comment: I would say that neither option is ok, but option 2 is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Do not stick values, especially numbers, in a separate table.  Keep them in the main table, where they can easily be fetched.

This also allows for *much* easier use of the number values in "range" testing.